# Is there a standard name for this algorithm?

Tags: computation

Computers are general purpose machines that can be programmed. Thus, computers can run any algorithm along with the given input. However, this means that computers must have built-in an algorithm for running other algorithms with inputs. A high level heading for this algorithm could be the following:

*Run_Algorithm(Algorithm X, Input I)*

Is there a standard name for this algorithm? The closest concept I could think of is "von Neumann architecture" but this is usually thought of as an architecture  and not algorithm.

Comment: Operative system.

Comment: Not all computers are general purpose and can be programmed. And even when a computer runs a program, there is no strict need for an algorithm that starts or runs other algorithms. Programs can be sequences of instructions directly acting on the CPU, without other mediation.

Comment: Else BIOS and Kernel are words that could be used with various meanings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: We are computers according to Turing. Is there any fixed algorithm we follow?

Comment: @JKusin Turing said no such thing. Ever.

Comment: @user4894 That exact phrase no, but Church of Turing, “in particular, a human calculator, provided with pencil and paper and explicit instructions, can be regarded as a kind of Turing machine.”  And Turing: “ Electronic computers are intended to carry out any definite rule of thumb process which could have been done by a human operator working in a disciplined but unintelligent manner”. I’m not sure of anything where if A can do everything B can do, we don’t call A a B.

Comment: @JKusin So when Turing said that a human can emulate a TM, you presented that as Turing saying that humans *are* TMs. And you seem to be doubling down. I find this weak sophistry to say the least. Please forgive, that's the least confrontational thing I could manage to say.

Comment: @JKusin Ok to be charitable, you are saying that a human is a TM, but you are perhaps open to the possibility that a human is not ONLY a TM. Is that fair? Otherwise you're playing word games and hoping nobody will notice.

Comment: @user4894 If a human with pen and paper can do *everything* a TM can do, albeit slower usually, we are computers. I’m almost certain Searle uses this terminology too when speaking *of the human* in the Chinese room following the instructions given to her.

Comment: @user4894 Humans are more than TMs almost certainly. I honestly find this language clearer in the long run in light of the Chinese room exp.

Comment: @JKusin Yes I think we're in agreement. A human can emulate a computer; in fact programmers "play computer" as a debugging technique, executing a fragment of code line by line, drawing pictures of what variable holds what value. If you believe humans are more than TMs, we're definitely in agreement. Many these days think that we're *only* TMs, and that I can't agree with. But I haven't got a great argument as to what that even means. If the mind is ultimately physical, but it's not a computation in the sense of Turing, then what is it exactly?

Comment: @user4894 yes, we can “play the computer” and yet we don’t learn Chinese in the process of performing the translating (or whatever) algorithm. It’s so easy to mess this up. But I think thats the lesson we have to take from current understanding

Answer (score 2):

the answer, in terms of turing machines, is a universal turing machine. A universal turing machine can simulate any other turing machine. Since Turing machines are (intuitively) algorithms, this holds.

If you want the answer for computer science more generally, since lambda calculus/ combinatory logic/post systems/ godel encodings are all equivalent, we can give a description in terms of these systems as well.

Comment: Thank you, "universal turing machine" was the exact term I was looking for. And the equivalent concepts as well.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close because this is a CS question, however, I'll just add a little more to the comments. Your question is fishing around, but has a muddled quality we can set straight.

1. A general purpose computer built from the Harvard or von Neumann architectures is an embodied [Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine.), and not all computers (like your digital wrist watch) way strive to be programmable. Many [microprocessors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprocessor) have specialized functions.
2. Yes, today's desktops, laptops, servers, etc. have not AN algorithm, but a series of algorithms called an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) which functions as an application to manage applications. This allows a single CPU with a single core to run multiple applications and users at the same time, something that wasn't always possible on computers. You can take a whole sequence of classes on OSes, but a part you might be interested in is called the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) which is an software object that manages the execution of [op codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) in the CPU. Managing threads and processes does require a set of [scheduling algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)).
3. When computer hardware comes online, it undergoes [booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting) (from "pull yourself up by your bootstraps") which might be understood as a hardware-implemented algorithm to change state of the system from unpowered to powered and usable; this involves using a software routine stored in firmware to execute a series of instructions to configure the state of the hardware to allow the operating system to assume control.
4. Computers are ridiculously complicated machines. My first machine had 5K of RAM and and a MOS 6502 microprocessor in a DIP which was quite advanced compared to ENIAC. Now, my phone puts that desktop to shame. It would help if you develop a generalized picture of how an operating systems works: I'd recommend [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). The authors do a good job of describing what is going on inside a typical OS, and they have their entire work online free.
5. What's important to understand is that there is a relationship between software and hardware such that "software" is just a series of state changes to the hardware, in the same way that the words on a page are just configuration of ink and paper. That is, software is a shorthand for thinking about how hardware changes. While understanding how an OS functions will clarify how programs are organized, stored, and run, to really understand philosophically what is going on with a computer, you need to understand the concepts behind the parts. I'd recommend Charles' Petzold's [*Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Software and Hardware*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Code/gYlQAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=petzold%20charles%20cod). It is unparalleled for it's technical sophistication and clarity from the notion of signaling, up to microprocessor design.

Good luck!

Comment: Very detailed and pragmatic answer with good suggestions for further research.

Answer (score 0):

when you click a .doc document in your desktop, then you "tell" the operating system to "run" ms-word (algorithm) with the .doc file as an input, so the .doc file "opens" in ms-word. This is not an algorithm, it is an operation. Hope this helps.